# Не могу получить заголовки объекта Response

Tags: angularjs, angular4, angular5

На сервере есть cors фильтр. В хроме в панели разработчика приходит ответ от сервера со всеми заголовками. По какой-то причине мой код не может получить заголовок и печатает null.

```
 login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginURL,
      { "type": "User", "id": null, "login": user.login, "password": user.password },
      {observe: 'response'}
    )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp.body['token']);
        console.log(resp.headers.get('Authorization'));
      }
      );
  }
```

body['token'] нормально выводится в консоль. А заголовок получить не удается.

Comment: Посмотрите что у вас приходит в ответе (body) и получайте нужное вам значение так: `resp.body.token`

Comment: ?? Я ж написал, что body и так выводится. А headers не получается получить(

Answer (score 0):

Не все заголовки доступны для чтения на клиентской стороне попробуйте ввывести на консоль все заголовки.

```
console.log(response.headers);
```

Если он приходит, то Вам надо заменить ключ заголовка на серверной стороне.

Еще можно попробовать так (Задать тип resp: Response):

```
.subscribe((resp: Response) => {
        console.log(resp.headers.get('Authorization'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки, проблема оказалась в cors фильтре на стороне сервера. Почему-то во всех примерах таких фильтров на просторах интернета не упоминалось, что нужно не только разрешить нужные заголовки в запросе, но и указать, какие заголовки мы сможем обрабатывать на клиенте.

Нужно добавить в response заголовок "Access-Control-Expose-Headers ".

Например вот так это выглядит в моем фильтре 
 response.setHeader("**Access-Control-Expose-Headers** ", "x-requested-with,origin,date, content-Type, accept, authorization");
   В нем перечисляем нужные нам заголовки.